# Fonts on serial console and framebuffer console

Tags: linux, fonts, terminal, console, framebuffer

I am working on framebuffer and serial console, serial console is basically a default console to see debug messages where framebuffer console is an advance console which can also show small graphics.

I am confused how character gets drawn differently on to serial and framebuffer console.

Comment: Are you asking why the text in one console appears differently to the other? i.e. one console might have colored text, the other doesn't?

Comment: Yes, it may or may not be, basically question is weather one console is printing the character by reading some fixed keymap and another one not taking care of, is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest reading this: [Linux Framebuffer on the Virtual Console](http://hacklab.cz/2012/04/22/usefulness-linux-framebuffer-virtual-console).

A serial console only has the ability to send and receive ASCII characters and escape codes, which are interpreted by whatever terminal emulator you're using (minicom, Hyperterminal, PuTTY etc.). More information on terminal emulation here: [Terminal Emulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)

The framebuffer console inplements a Linux console on your system's physical display. Because the display is rendered using a pixel map, it is also able to allow graphics to be displayed.